# Data Grid View is Transparent

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm creating a dataGridView on C#, but it becomes transparent. I can see all the things through the GridView.![I can see my desktop]. What can I do? I already tried to change the color.

Comment: Can you be more specific, Web-Form? Win-Form? Wpf? MVC?  We need more details.

Comment: Sorry, It's Windows Forms!